# I deleted a folder out of my xcode project by mistake, where does it go to?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, xcode4, cordova

I deleted it out of the folder view in the left sidebar. It's gone from inside the apps folder and it isn't in the trash. It isn't letting me undo inside xcode either. It's a phonegap project and I deleted the 'www' folder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally, the folders in XCode do not represent real folders in your filesystem.
Did the folder contain certain files? Can you check if these files are still present in the root of your project folder (via finder)?
If yes, the simplest way would be to just create a new folder an drag the files into it again.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have a backup. Xcode 4 deletes the files directly, rather than moving them to the trash. Please, file a bug report about this at [bugreport.apple.com](http://bugreport.apple.com)!

Comment: In a system designed for professional users the action delete should result in real  deleting, and not just moving out of the way. Just my two cent.

Comment: I disagree Viking, move to trash worked just fine for 10 years... I have lost small amounts of code to things where Xcode greedily deletes files of the same name in you project.